# Is answering a question with a question not permitted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

In [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/was-eisav-jewish), why was [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/was-eisav-jewish/9043#9043) deleted?  The answer is a question intended to demonstrate reasoning -- the question asked if Eisav was Jewish, using Yaakov as an example as Jewish by birth, and the answer tried to show the flaw in that reasoning.  (Answer text: If Yaakov was Jewish, was it by birth or by accepting God and torah? If the latter, this has no bearing on Eisav.)  The answer was deleted as off-topic and I'm trying to understand the problem.

(Sorry if Meta isn't the right place to ask this either.  I couldn't leave a comment on the deleted answer.)

Comment: It wasn't deleted as off-topic: it was converted into a comment on the question.

Comment: @msh210: oh, I missed the addition of the comment - thanks.  I followed the faq link from the answer and got to the entry about off-topic questions/answers.

Comment: There's a FAQ link? Wow. I didn't realize that. I guess it only shows up for the "deleted" content's author. What's the text, and what's the link to?

Comment: "Why was this question deleted?  See the faq (link)".  The FAQ link is http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to write this up as a bug. Either the text and link should be different for such conversions or the FAQ text there should include "maybe it was converted to a comment" as an explicit possibility.

Comment: Oh, and the response to your title ought to be "What, you thought maybe this was a Jewish website?" ;^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the answer to a [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/was-eisav-jewish#comment-11932) on the question. Like Gershon [said](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/is-answering-a-question-with-a-question-not-permitted/302#302), the answer effectively raises an issue but doesn't provide a definite resolution to the question, so I thought it fit more as a comment than as an answer. It was definitely on-topic.

Unfortunately, the system marks a converted-to-comment question as "deleted" and doesn't automatically indicate that it was converted to a comment. I probably should have left a comment to that effect, to make it clear. Sorry about that.

(Here's probably the best place to ask this. A comment on the question would have worked, too.)

Answer (score 1):

That answer was a comment on the question. An answer gives something definate.

Comment: It was submitted as an answer and converted to a comment later by somebody else (which I hadn't noticed).